# What are holdings of a Contract?

Tags: tokens, nft

When I check [an NFT](https://opensea.io/assets/0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb/8237) on [eterscan.io](https://etherscan.io/tokenholdings?a=0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb) I'm seeing that that contract has many holdings.

[image: Screenshot from Etherscan]

I think that these are total ERC20 transfers that put in the contract. Probably from NFT consumers like Opensea or Rarible. Am I right?

1. Someone can explain to me what are these?
2. When NFT transferred to anyone. Are these holdings move to the new owner too?

Thanks for your responses.